# How do I leave padding-like gap in a specific direction?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to learn about data visualization, and I would like to create a space on the right side of my chart so that I can move my legend inside without it overlapping the data. I am not sure if this is possible. Is there any way you can help me with this?

[image]

[image]

```py
bins = [float('-inf'), 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, float('inf')]
labels = ['1960 and Older', '1970s', '1980s', '1990s', '2000 and Younger']
df['AgeGroup'] = pd.cut(df['Year'], bins=bins, labels=labels)

fam_map = {3: 'Low', 4: 'Medium', 5: 'High'}
df['FamLabel'] = df['Familiar_with_capsicum'].map(fam_map)

ax = avg_df.plot(kind='bar', color=['#00dd00','#dd0000','#0000bb' ], figsize=(8, 4), )
ax.set_xlabel('Age Groups')
ax.set_ylabel('Average Familiarity with Capsicum')
ax.set_title('Average Familiarity Level of Capsicum by Age Groups', fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')

ax.legend(title='Familiarity Level', title_fontsize=12, loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.03,.5))

plt.show()
```

- I tried moving the legend around by changing its location, and also changed the sizes of the bars, but it didn't make sense.
- Then, I attempted to add new space for the data to leave it empty and create a gap, but I was not able to accomplish this. Perhaps this is something I can try in the future when I gain more experience.
- I am looking for new solutions this time. It's probably an extra/unnecessary effort, but if it's possible, I would like to learn about it

Comment: What is the content of `avg_df`? It is not in code anywhere. Can you please print it out as text

Comment: I don't recommend what you're doing, it looks [janky](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/janky). However, see [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxr3G.png). You must extend the range of the xticks and then replace those tick labels with empty strings.